# Parallel light failed to work, one light get's blow other remains good. How to get it working?

Tags: parallel, light, batteries

I'm using a mobile battery (4V) to power the two (each takes 3.0V) light in parallel since series circuit won't work with one battery. After connecting the wire, for a short time it did work. Then one light stopped working. 1 ohm resistor is given to limit the current. Yet it did not work. Can you tell me how this circuit is going to work properly?

Comment: Telling us the value of your resistor (1 ohm) doesn't mean anything without knowing the current draw.   If a light worked 'for a short time', very very very likely you are passing it too much current.  What's the rated power of these lights????

Comment: http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/ledcalc.php